# In manage products, the “inventory” tab is blank

Tags: magento

In the Admin Panel, when I go to Manage Products, on all individual products, the “Inventory” tab is blank.

When I look at the page code for this control panel page, there’s nothing inside the div:

```
<div style="" id="product_info_tabs_inventory_content"></div>
```

So whatever’s supposed to be loading the inventory data is failing. On the other hand, all the other tabs are showing content correctly.

I’m using Magento Community 1.7.0.2.  I’ve got a couple plugins, but they’re not related to the inventory (e.g. one’s for mailing list, another’s for gift cards)

Is there a particular piece of code I should be looking at to fix this?

I’ve cleared the caches, indexes, and rebuilt the compilation (and turned it off).

As a footnote, now whenever I make a change to to a product, it causes the cache to be invalidated  (the Block HTML to be specific) - but I'm not sure if this is related or if it's a red herring.

Comment: If you edit a product it is cached inside of a block so it's fine that this happens depending on your theme setup. As for products now showing up, can you please provide an image of your product list? There might be a setting that is filtering the results!

Comment: Could you disable your caches. Turn off the compilation and check var/log to see anything here?

Comment: I did try turning off the caches. Tried rebuilding the compilation and disabling compilation entirely.

The products themselves are showing up in the Manage Products list. It's just when I go into an individual product, there's a list of  "inventory"

Comment: Try that again...

I did try turning off the caches. Tried rebuilding the compilation and disabling compilation entirely. And nothing of interest shows up in the logs. (I've got error reporting & logging turned on.)

The products themselves are showing up in the Manage Products list. It's just when I go into an individual product, the one screen of data isn't being populated. (I can put in other data, like pricing, images, etc)

Here's a screenshot of it: http://i1287.photobucket.com/albums/a623/samco327/magentoblankinventoryscreen_zps85d2f051.png

Comment: Additional information: I copied the database from the server to a second dev environment (where it had been working), and now that env is showing the same error. Which leads me to think it's a database-related issue (as opposed to corrupt files, etc). Over the last few days, a user added a large number of products and images. Maybe this is related to my issue(s)?

Comment: Figured it out. Plugin had gone bad. I made the mistake of assuming that if the plugin was working before, it would continue to be working later. Disabled everything and re-enabled pieces until it broke again. So disabling that one piece now 'fixes' everything. (Now, of course, I have to fix the plugin, but that's another post...)

Comment: which plugin? please @SamC

Comment: I don't really remember, this was a year and a half ago ... But here's what I do remember from troubleshooting - Go down the list of tabs on the product page (General, Prices, Meta Info, Images, etc). If the specific tab you're on is broken, start by looking at that specific plugin. If it's not that, take a look at whatever the tab _right before_ the broken one is. It's likely something is broken at the end of it, and is spilling over into the next tab.

Comment: Failing all that, the best thing to do is to disable all the modules in /app/etc/modules by updating their XML (which should un-break things). And then re-enabling them one at a time until things break again.